# How can I get user basic information (wechat API)?

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram, wechat-official-account

I have an application that uses UnionID Mechanism to get user info (nickname, language code). After researching, According to WeChat's official description, this method will no longer output user information after 12/27/2021. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmtDc.png) https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/offiaccount/User_Management/Get_users_basic_information_UnionID.html

Do we have another way to get user info (nickname, language code)?
I suffer from this issue for a long time. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: what do you use to develop your application? app 、miniprogram、common website、official-account website or the Third Platform?

Comment: My application use Official account,

Comment: this docs may help you：https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/offiaccount/en/OA_Web_Apps/JS-SDK.html